# Alternative method to delete child element from parent besides on delete cascade

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables:

1. Warehouse (Parent)
2. Subwarehouse (Child)

> Here is the creation of tables

```
//Create Warehouse Table
    function einv_createWarehouseTable($conn, $db_type){
        // Create SQL Statement To Create Table according to Database
        $sql = "
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `einv_warehouse` (
                  `einv_wh_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `einv_wh_code` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
                  `einv_wh_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  `einv_wh_desc` TEXT NOT NULL,
                  `einv_wh_remark` TEXT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`einv_wh_id`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
                ";


    //Create Sub Warehouse Table
function einv_createSubWarehouseTable($conn, $db_type){
    // Create SQL Statement To Create Table according to Database
    $sql = "
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `einv_subwarehouse` (
              `einv_whs_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `einv_whs_wh_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,                  
              `einv_whs_code` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
              `einv_whs_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
              `einv_whs_desc` TEXT NOT NULL,
              `einv_whs_remark` TEXT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`einv_whs_id`),
              FOREIGN KEY (`einv_whs_wh_id`) REFERENCES einv_warehouse(`einv_wh_id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
            ";
```

I would like to be able to delete my parent table alongside clearing the entire child data.

I'd prefer an **alternative method** besides using **on delete cascade** which will result me into altering the table.

It is troublesome because these codings would require a drop and install process which is time consuming since there are many existing tables.

> tl;dr - another method to delete all child data when selected parent id is
>   deleted
>
> besides using on delete cascade

Here is my delete sql in my function.php page:

```
base_executeSQL("DELETE FROM einv_warehouse WHERE einv_wh_id = " . $whid . "");

base_executeSQL("DELETE FROM einv_subwarehouse WHERE einv_whs_id = " . $whid . "");
```

Comment: I dont know if i understood you but try to use transaction and first remove all children rows then remove parent row

Comment: ah that seems viable :) @szapio

Comment: Please tell us why you don't want the on delete cascade solution. Another way is triggers, but in practice that's basically the same.

Comment: i have a huge database and many tables. dropping and recreating would be time consuming. Thus, just wonder if there's an alternative to it @jarlh

Comment: triggers don't seem applicable for this too. thanks anyway :p @jarlh

Comment: @HishamMuhd i hope that will be acceptable :), but if deleting takes to much time, check how much time take update, and you can try add one more column `deleted` and mark rows to delete, and at night (if there is less traffic) you can run a script which delete all marked rows (and of course dont show records marked as deleted before you delete them)

Comment: Nice, i will do so! thanks once again :D @szapio

Comment: Another solutions would be to do the two delete queries inside a stored procedure and call the procedure in your PHP code